# My strchr() is slower than the original, Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio

[strchr()](http://clc-wiki.net/wiki/strchr). I assume it's the same implementation in VS 2015. I copied it in a new function and tried. I have a big difference for a char `array[15001767]` (stored in the heap), 3 ms original, 17 ms mine.

Where this difference is located?

```
char *teststr(const char *s, int c)
{
    while (*s != (char)c)
        if (!*s++)
            return 0;
    return (char *)s;
}

int main()
{
    DWORD pa;

    char *test = (char*)HeapAlloc(HeapCreate(NULL, 0, 0), NULL, 15001767);
    ReadFile(CreateFileW(L"MyFile.txt", GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, NULL, NULL), test, 15001767, &pa, NULL);

    //strchr(test, '£');
    teststr(test, '£');
```

}

Comment: Perhaps theirs is written in assembler using the `repne scasb` instruction.

Comment: Names of the standard library are reservce for the implementation. Don't use them in your code. Also you are required to provide the code **in** the question, not just link to it.

Comment: I obviously changed the name of my function. In any tests I made, even without a new function, I have the same duration which is around 17 ms.

Comment: Maybe if you showed the assembler for each?

Comment: Please consider making the question clear and show us your effort by posting relevant pieces of code.

Comment: The code is added.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in this comparison of different `strchr` implementations I knocked up, using the standard library (MSVC), OP's function, and two assembler versions, one of which is told the string length, the other has to find it first. That second one is still faster than OP's routine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define LEN 15001767
#define REPS 100

char array[LEN];

char *asmstrchrA(const char *s, int c)
// knows the string length
{
    __asm {
        push    es
        mov     ax,ds
        mov     es,ax
        mov     edi,s
        mov     ecx,LEN
        mov     eax,c
        cld
        repne   scasb
        jz      foundA
        xor     edi,edi         ; not found
        inc     edi
    foundA:
        dec     edi
        mov     s,edi
        pop     es
    }
    return (char *)s;
}    

char *asmstrchrB(const char *s, int c)
// finds the string length first
{
    __asm {
        push    es
        mov     ax,ds
        mov     es,ax

        mov     edi,s           ; find string length
        xor     eax,eax
        mov     ecx,-1
        cld
        repne   scasb
        mov     ecx,edi
        sub     ecx,s

        mov     edi,s           ; find char
        mov     eax,c
        cld
        repne   scasb
        jz      foundB
        xor     edi,edi         ; not found
        inc     edi
    foundB:
        dec     edi
        mov     s,edi
        pop     es
    }
    return (char *)s;
}    

char *OPstrchr(const char *s, int c)
// from OP's link
{
    while (*s != (char)c)
        if (!*s++)
            return 0;
    return (char *)s;
}    

int main (void) {
    clock_t start;
    int i;
    char * cptr;

    memset(array, '1', LEN-1);
    array[LEN-5] = '2';

    start = clock();
    for(i=0; i<REPS; i++)
        cptr = OPstrchr(array, '2');
    printf("OPstrchr   %p, time = %f seconds\n", (void*)cptr, (double)(clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    start = clock();
    for(i=0; i<REPS; i++)
        cptr = asmstrchrA(array, '2');
    printf("asmstrchrA %p, time = %f seconds\n", (void*)cptr, (double)(clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    start = clock();
    for(i=0; i<REPS; i++)
        cptr = asmstrchrB(array, '2');
    printf("asmstrchrB %p, time = %f seconds\n", (void*)cptr, (double)(clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    start = clock();
    for(i=0; i<REPS; i++)
        cptr = strchr(array, '2');
    printf("strchr     %p, time = %f seconds\n", (void*)cptr, (double)(clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
OPstrchr   0125F5A2, time = 7.488000 seconds
asmstrchrA 0125F5A2, time = 1.248000 seconds
asmstrchrB 0125F5A2, time = 2.512000 seconds
strchr     0125F5A2, time = 1.045000 seconds
```

Comment: My objective is to find a `strchr()` reverse function, because [strrchr()](http://clc-wiki.net/wiki/strrchr) writes for each char found and starts at position zero. I want avoid useless writes + start position 0 because I assume it is slower. When I tried it manually because I didn't find a reverse function, I got this horrible duration.

Comment: Sorry, is this a different question now? `strrchr` would start at the end of the string, and scan backwards. What gets written?

Comment: Yes it is a linked question. I only assumed it starts at position 0 because with a char at the end of the file, the time for `strchr()` and `strrchr()` to search it, is the same.

Comment: It has to start at position 0 because C does not know the string length. So it either finds the string length then works backwards (*ref 1*), or combines both operations (as your `strchr` example does). As it happens, when I implemented (*ref 1*) my assembler `strrchr` was slightly faster than the library, but probably only because the searched char is near the end of the string.

Comment: Yes, it is probably because the char is to the end of string. So, my only way is to write my own implementation of `strrchr()`? There is no way better than the assembler?

Comment: What's wrong with using the library function? They will be hard to beat, unless they are crap implementations supplied with a MPU cross compiler.

Comment: `strrchr()` will consume more resources than a function which starts at the end of a char array, especially if this char is found a lot of times, inevitably. That's why I try to find another way, without use C++ functions/objects.